# downcase remove duplicates rails save database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do a simple downcase and remove duplicates in rails. Also save to the database.

```
Tag.all.each do |tag|
  tag_name = tag.name.downcase!
  tag_name.uniq!
  tag.save!
end
```

Error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `uniq!' for nil:NilClass
```

Also tried with pluck

```
tag_name = Tag.pluck(:name)
tag_name.each do |tag|
  name = tag.downcase!
  name.uniq!
end
```

Error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `uniq!' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: This is not how you remove duplicates from the database.

Comment: Your logic is wrong.  You can't apply .uniq to a single object of the Tag class.  You apply .uniq to an array (or AR relation) of all objects in the Tag class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used group_by to find filter query.

```
  found_tags = Tag.all.group_by { |tag| tag.name.downcase }
  found_tags.each do |key, val|
    if found_tags[key].count > 1
      tag_to_keep = val.shift

      val.each do |t|
        t.taggings.update_all(tag_id: tag_to_keep.id)
        t.destroy!
      end

      tag_to_keep.update(name: tag_to_keep.name.downcase)
    end
  end
```